# Use Different WCF Services in Dev and Production for WPF Application

Tags: wpf, wcf, configuration, production-environment

I have a WPF application that accesses a number of WCF services. The WCF service addresses used in dev are different than those used in production (though their WSDL signatures are identical). What is the best way to setup the config files so that the proper service url is used for each type of build?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a NANT process after build that change the config in a different way, here a [discussion about that](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/02/21/Change-config-file-with-NAnt.aspx). An alternative is to create a MSbuild custom task, [as discussed here](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2006/04/11/74844.aspx).